# Sonarqube 6.7 upgrade failure "Unrecoverable indexation failures"

Tags: sonarqube

We are attempting to upgrade from SonarQube 5.6.7 to SonarQube 6.7.2.  I followed the steps outlined here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading.

I have > 300GB available on the partition that elastic search is using so it doesn't seem to be related to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317780/sonarqube-upgrade-to-6-7-unrecoverable-indexation-failures).

**The exception:**

```
2018.03.21 11:13:10 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecoverable indexation failures
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexingListener$1.onFinish(IndexingListener.java:39)
        at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.stop(BulkIndexer.java:117)
        at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.doIndex(IssueIndexer.java:247)
        at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.indexOnStartup(IssueIndexer.java:95)
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.indexUninitializedTypes(IndexerStartupTask.java:68)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.execute(IndexerStartupTask.java:55)
        at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:84)
        at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:80)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:196)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$400(Platform.java:46)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$1(Platform.java:121)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:121)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Partition configuration:**

```
[dssc100[DEV]@omhqp13890 bin]$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
... Other volumes omitted ...
/dev/mapper/Volume00-upapps
                     464422672 127511888 313323572  29% /upapps
```

At one point I did attempt to run the upgrade with the logging set to debug.  This generated 6GB of log files and I was unable to find anything that seemed out of the ordinary.

We've got around 6k projects in this installation, some of which have several years of history.  I would like to maintain that rich history, what can I do/look for as a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have hit <strike>[SONAR-10502](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10502)</strike>, which is (will be) fixed in 6.7.3 and 7.1.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  It looks like the 6.7.3 release isn't planned until April, is there a way to get access to the development branch so I can test?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try building and testing with that.